# Overcome 1000 bucket limit in S3 / use access points

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 1 s3 bucket per customer. Customers are external entities and they dont share data with anyone else. I write to S3 and customer reads from S3. As per this architecture, I can only scale to 1000 buckets as there is a limit to s3 buckets per account. I was hoping to use APs to create 1 AP per customer and put data in one bucket. The customer can then read the files from the bucket using AP.

`Bucket000001/prefix01 .   -> customeraccount1`

`Bucket000001/prefix02 .   -> customeraccount2`
...

S3 access points require you to set policy for a IAM user in access point as well as the bucket level. If I have 1000s of IAM users, do I need to set policy for each of them in the bucket? This would result in one giant policy. there is a max policy size in the bucket, so I may not be able to do that. 
Is this the right use case where access points can help?

Comment: what kind of user?

Comment: Please edit your Question to tell us more about your actual goal. "S3 access points" are unlikely to be an appropriate solution for your requirement, but we would need to know more information before suggesting the best method. First, please let us know what you mean by "user" -- are they IAM Users, or application users? When you say "share a bucket", do you really mean "provide access to a subdirectory within a bucket"? Can you provide us with an example of how the users will actually be using the bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein hopefully the edits answer your questions

Comment: @TuanVA User is a customer account who can read the data from S3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended approach would be:

- **Do NOT assign IAM Users to your customers.** These types of AWS credentials should only be used by your internal staff and your own applications.
- You should provide a web application (or an API) where customers can **authenticate against your own user database** (or you could use Amazon Cognito to manage authentication).
- Once authenticated, the application should grant access either to a **web interface to access Amazon S3**, or the application should **provide temporary credentials** for accessing Amazon S3 (more details below).
- **Do not use one bucket per customer.** This is not scalable. Instead, **store all customer data in ONE bucket**, with each user having their own folder. There is no limit on the amount of data you can store in Amazon S3. This also makes it easier for you to manage and maintain, since it is easier to perform functions across all content rather than having to go into separate buckets. (An exception might be if you wish to segment buckets by customer location (region) or customer type. But do *not* use one bucket per customer. There is no reason to do this.)
- When granting access to Amazon S3, **assign permissions at the folder-level** to ensure customers only see their own data.

**Option 1: Access via Web Application**

If your customers access Amazon S3 via a web application, then you can code that application to enforce security at the folder level. For example, when they request a list of files, only display files within their folder.

This security can be managed totally within your own code.

**Option 2: Access via Temporary Credentials**

If your customers use programmatic access (eg using the AWS CLI or a custom app running on their systems), then:

- The customer should **authenticate to your application** (how this is done will vary depending upon how you are authenticating users)
- Once authenticated, the application should **generate temporary credentials using the [AWS Security Token Service (STS)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)**. While generating the credentials, grant access to Amazon S3 but specify the customer's folder in the ARN (eg `arn:aws:s3:::storage-bucket/customer1/*`) so that they can only access content within *their* folder.
- Return these temporary credentials to the customer. They can then use these credentials to make API calls directly to Amazon S3 (eg from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or a custom app). They will be limited to their own folder.

This approach is **commonly done with mobile applications**. The mobile app authenticates against the backend, receives temporary credentials, then uses those credentials to interact directly against S3. Thus, the back-end app is only used for authentication.

Examples on YouTube:

- [5 Minutes to Amazon Cognito: Federated Identity and Mobile App Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arZ2zj_F4LA)
- [Overview Security Token Service STS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cxSqMHgDGs)
- [AWS: Use the Session Token Service to Securely Upload Files to S3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_csSXc_GNU)

Comment: Would I need to touch the bucket policy when I need to grant/revoke access for a customer when using STS?

Comment: No. A Bucket Policy is generally only used when granting Public access, or access based on certain conditions (eg IP addresses). In the above scenario, permissions can be specified when the app creates the temporary credentials via STS or Cognito. There should be no reason for your to use a Bucket Policy.

Comment: "Do not use one bucket per customer. This is not scalable. Instead, store all customer data in ONE bucket, with each user having their own folder. There is no limit on the amount of data you can store in Amazon S3."  I've seen a lot of people trip up on this (myself included).  I still can't really find "why" AWS chose this restriction?  If we can have unlimited data in S3, why not unlimited buckets?  It's concerning that maybe the underlying infrastructure can't handle it.  Even just the optics for a customer that their data is in a shared bucket with their competition is not ideal.

Comment: I also thought it was intuitive like OP to use IAM users.  Especially when creating them allows you to create programatic access keys.    I just happened to stumble upon the 5000 IAM user limit in the doco.  Again I can't find why this restriction was made?  Each of our servers have their own permanent keys to use the AWS apis.  IAM users are put into a user group with user-name restricted ARNs on build.   IAM users does this perfectly if not for the 5000 limit.

Comment: I read "I should just use cognito instead" (not sure why other than the 5000 IAM user limit), but spent three days trying to get the same outcome but had to give up in the end.  Read similar frustrations on forums (https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/m77p5g/aws_cognito_amplify_auth_bad_bugged_baffling/).  Seems more geared toward human users authenticating via OAuth/Google than for servers.  Puzzling.

Comment: I've since learned:

In the S3 Bucket documentation it says "An Amazon S3 bucket name is globally unique, and the namespace is shared by all AWS accounts.". I initially though this meant all AWS accounts which I control (federated), but this actually means anybody's account, even ones you don't control.  I think this should better explained, maybe in bold and red in the doco.  This was very unexpected, but it makes sense now why there's a cap on buckets.  Probably to stop squatting like domains.  I would have expected bucket names would be qualified by my account id or something in URLs.

Answer (score 2):

We have some way to achieve your goal.

- use IAM group to grant access to a folder. Create a group, add a user to a group, and assign a role to the group to access the folder.
- Another way is to use bucket policy (`${aws:username}` in Condition) to grant Access to User-Specific Folders. Refer to this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/