# How to handle bucket limits on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We create an s3 bucket for each client to keep their data separated. The buckets are accessed by clients via Amazon's SFTP service.

I'm reading that there is a 1000 bucket limit per account. What are the work arounds for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overcome 1000 bucket limit in S3 / use access points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833355/overcome-1000-bucket-limit-in-s3-use-access-points)

Comment: Don't assign one bucket per customer. Consider one (or multiple) bucket(s) and use unique prefixes to separate tenants.

Comment: To share the same bucket, you can use: [IAM policy elements: Variables and tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)